# how do I prevent typescript tsc from compiling ../node_modules?

Tags: typescript, npm

I have an existing project and have cloned the typescript/node/express sample project into a subfolder. When I run `tsc -p .` in the sub-folder, I get compilation errors because tsc is scanning `../node_modules`. How do I tell tsc to not ascend the directory tree?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the node_modules directory being compiled by using the "exclude" option in the [tsconfig.json file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```